# Are there any rinkeby testnet faucets that don't require social network accounts?

Tags: faucets

Are there any rinkeby testnet Faucet's that don't require social network accounts?

https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet wants requests centralized twitter/g+/fb posts.

Comment: My bad, just a few days ago you could do it with a bithub account, seems like it changed.

Comment: Yeah, the message says `GitHub authentication discontinued at the official request of GitHub`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update Oct 2022:**
The above URL is dead as Goerli is now the only Ethereum testnet still working. All others including Rinkeby have been deprecated and no longer work.

Here's a reliable Goerli faucet to get free Goerli testEth from Alchemy - https://goerlifaucet.com

Comment: Tried it, they claimed that they sent it, but couldn't find the Transaction hash in the Explorer https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/ ...

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen This'd happened once for me too. Try again with new address and try after some time.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Comment: Confirming that goerlifaucet.com.works reliably. There is a daily limit, but you can get more for free every 24 hours.

Answer (score 10):

**[Working in 2021-22]**
The only working and fast faucet right now gives you 0.1 Eth without rate limit you can make multiple requests.
https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby.
Huge thanks to Chainlink team.
Hope the official faucet gets fixed soon.

Comment: I've just tested that one and it did work.

Comment: @iaforek do you think its better to highlight in answer in bold [Working 2021-22] as the accepted answer and other answers does not seem to work anymore ?

Comment: This one was the only working for me. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Works!! Jan 2022

Comment: Worked for me on Mar 2022, but only early in the Morning, US Eastern Time

Answer (score 8):

https://testnet.help/en/ethfaucet/rinkeby

with no questions . Other answers here : one is not work,the other one records your mail

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore

Comment: May be they'll fix it . Now it doesnt work

Comment: They're working now when they have funds. see battery. Most of the time they have not

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

http://rinkeby-faucet.com/

It will give you 0.001 ETH (Rinkeby Testnet) without a social network account.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: I have used it a few times this month and it works. Not sure the of the frequency you can request at, but I did twice in the last few hours.

Answer (score 3):

[This Rinkeby Faucet](https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/) is also a great option!

It is a fast (less than 30 seconds when I use), reliable, and doesn't require twitter login or auth.

It allows for 0.10 Eth per day and even has some fun animations when requests are submitted!

Answer (score 2):

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby
Just tested this out! It's working

Comment: Works!! Jan 2022

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get 0.01 ETH from https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet. You'll need to connect with metamask, then navigate back to the same URL, enter a captcha, then viola, Ether!

Answer (score 0):

This one works like a charm:

https://rinkeby.faucet.epirus.io/#

- no questions
- no captcha
- no registration
- no nothing

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore

Comment: This link does not working.

Comment: On the first try. "The server encountered an error. You may have been rate-limited or the service may be down."

Comment: The link is working for me, and I get that error too now. :/

Answer (score 0):

As of today (January 24, 2022), [this](https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby) works perfectly. It sends 0.1 ETH to your address. You can use it multiple times a day. It is also, fast.

A huge thank you to their team for providing this to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

as of 2/9/2022 https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby does not work fir rinkeby eth, but it does for other testnet tokens.

Answer (score 0):

https://rinkebyfaucet.com/ give 0.5 ETH for registered users (every 24 hrs)