# Is there a benefit to using one testnet over another?

Tags: testnets, rinkeby

We have been using rinkeby, but the faucet is often offline.

Is there any reason to use rinkeby over goerli or another one?

Answer (score 1):

- If you are looking for a comparison between testnets, see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/comparison-of-the-different-testnets).
- And if you are looking for rinkeby's faucet, see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/119823/86679).