# Is Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet down?

Tags: rinkeby

So I am currently following a tutorial and it apparently needs this?, anyways the question I have is is Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet not working I created a twitter post put in the url for it and it came back with a message saying. insufficient funds for gas * (something) + value what is going on and what does it means

btw I am really new to all this stuff

Comment: There are a few alternatives here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30659/are-there-any-rinkeby-testnet-faucets-that-dont-require-social-network-accounts, faucets go out of order frequently.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately there are quite a spam accounts (been there!). Here's a reliable faucet as it's created by Alchemy - I can get testETH every day https://goerlifaucet.com.

Btw Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running due to the recent Ethereum Merge. The other ones including Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to and you should not go to any twitter account. They can be scammers.

If you want some test ETH from Rinkeby, then visit the website of Rinkeby faucet.
https://rinkebyfaucet.com/

Then copy your wallet address from metamask and paste this website and click on "send me eth"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm unfortunately there are quite a spam accounts (been there!). Here's a reliable faucet as it's created by Alchemy - I can get testETH every day https://goerlifaucet.com.

Btw Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running due to the recent Ethereum Merge. The other ones including Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan have been deprecated.